# iOS 10.1 platform for Xcode 7.3

Tags: ios, xcode

I have xcode 7.3.1, and for some reason I can't install xcode 8, but I strongly need to test my application on iOS 10.1 device. So my question is: can I test in iOS 10.1 with xcode 7.3.1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know one trick that will help you to do this. First of all you need to download xcode 8 or 8.1 .dmg file, but dont install. Here the link to download .dmg file of xcode 8.1 https://developer.apple.com/services-account/download?path=/Developer_Tools/Xcode_8.1/Xcode_8.1.xip.

Once you download xcode, please do next steps. Click right button on just downloaded xcode 8.1 and click Show package contents->Contents->Developer->Platform->iPhoneOS.platform-DeviceSupport, here you can see platform on which you can test you apps. So just copy folder 10.1 and paste at the same path in your xcode 7.3.1. When you will connect your device with iOS 10.1, you will have to wait for a several minutes and then you can test your apps from xcode 7.3.1 on iOS 10.1. Please, feel free to ask any details.

Comment: I also had xcode 8.1 downloaded previously. This is amazing trick, thank you a lot, you saved my day!!